# Call another function inside bootbox callback function

Tags: javascript, angular, bootbox

Hi I have a function which needs to be called on callback of bootbox prompt.

//Bootbox function

```
  refundfn = () => {
      let refund;       
      bootbox.prompt({
          title: "Partial Amount",
          inputType: 'number',
          buttons: {
              cancel: {
                  label: 'Full Refund'
              },
              confirm: {
                  label: 'Partial Refund'
              }
          },
          callback: function (result) {
              if (result == null) {
                  refund = document.getElementById("trRefundAmnt").innerHTML; 
                  this.refundAPICall(refund);
              } else {
                  refund = result; 
                  this.refundAPICall(refund);
              }
          }
      });  
  }
```

//Need to be called function

```
  refundAPICall = (refundAmnt) => {
      this.spinner = true;
      let orderId = document.getElementById("trOrderId").innerHTML;
      let systemId = document.getElementById("trSysId").innerHTML;
      let response = this.apiService.getRefund(systemId, orderId, refundAmnt).subscribe(
          success => {
              this.spinner = false;
              this.toastr.success("Success");
          }, error => {
              this.spinner = false;
              if (error.error.errorCode == 403) {
                  this.toastr.error(error.error.errorMessage);
              } else {
                  this.toastr.error(error.error.errors[0].userMessage);
              }
          }
      );
  }
```

But I`m not able to do it. Getting error TypeError: this.refundAPICall is not a function

Comment: remove the `this`

Comment: ^^ That.  `this` has a different meaning depending on where it's used.  If you want to refer to a specific meaning of `this`, it's usually better to keep a reference to it at the point you know for sure what it is (`var _this = this;`, for example) and then use that instead (`_this.refundAPICall(refund);`)